# Tethering - Sharing mobile network to LAN

Tags: android, kotlin, nat, socks, tethering

I am working on an Android 10 device, which have 4G access, Wifi and Ethernet port. I do not have root. I am researching a *ethernet tethering* solution.

This Android device will have LAN/ethernet connection to another component (lets say a PC). The LAN network will not have access to the internet. Idea is to share 4G connection of Android device to the LAN and that PC.

In the settings screen of the Android, I can only see *bluetooth tethering* and *USB tethering*, but **not** wifi or ethernet ones.

I am considering:

1. Ethernet tethering directly, if possible.
2. Some kind of NAT in the Android.
3. A SOCKS PROXY server in the Android.

I can see some github repositories like https://github.com/edveen/AndroidSocks5Proxy, but they are old and on the second one, my antivirus is even reporting some issues in the lib files.

Or maybe a https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd would be usable, although not only http trafic will need to be shared.

Is it even feasible? And what would be the *easiest* way to have some proof of concept for this?

Comment: You should make your Android device a hotspot. Other devices then connect to your hotspot. You dont use your earlier LAN.

Comment: I do not see that possibility for wifi tethering / create mobile hotspot in the android, so I would need to try by code - how?

Comment: If you're able to upgrade the device to Android 11, you would see an ethernet tethering option.  I don't think it's available until Android 11.